# Pandas - get values from list of tuples and map them to values on new columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe, `df_match`:

```
 #   Column                                Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                                --------------  ----- 
 0   match_id                              680 non-null    int64 
 1   league_id                             680 non-null    object
 2   from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11  680 non-null    object
```

where each row on `from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11` column keeps a list of tuples, like so:

`df_match.sample(1)`:

```
...
None      match_id league_id  from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11
167       243221   26         [(79066, GKP), (82634, MID), (79578, FWD), (34765, DEF), (23476, WING), (32456, MID),(55897, DEF),(45675, MID),(32345, FWD),(45765,FWD),(12354, WING)]
```

---

**GOAL**

Now I would like to set X/Y coordinates for each player on the field (using only coord X here in order to simplify it), per match (row)

Each player on `from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11` needs an X value. So I need a list of newly created X columns, like so:

```
    X_columns = ["home_player_X1", "home_player_X2", "home_player_X3","home_player_X4", "home_player_X5", 
                 "home_player_X6", "home_player_X7", "home_player_X8", "home_player_X9","home_player_X10", "home_player_X11",
```

---

Lastly, each position has an arbitrary set of X values. (When there's more than one option, it can be ANY one of them, randomly chosen)

```
GKP = 1
DEF = [3,4]
WING = [2,5]
MID = [6,7,8]
FWD = [9,10,11]
```

---

My aim here is to map -at each row, players positions to an X coordinate, ending up with:

```
None      match_id league_id  from_away_player_1_to_away_player_11 /
167       243221   26         [(79066, GKP), (82634, MID), (79578, FWD), (34765, DEF), (23476, WING), (32456, MID),(55897, DEF),(45675, MID),(32345, FWD),(45765,FWD),(12354, WING)] /

          home_player_X1 home_player_X2 home_player_X3 home_player_X4
          1              7              10             3
          home_player_X5 home_player_X6 home_player_X7 home_player_X8 
          5              7              4              7
          home_player_X9 home_player_X10 home_player_X11
          10             10              2
```

---

**How can I do this mapping based on the position/value condition with pandas?**

I started thinking of iterating through the dataframe with:

```
for index, value in df_match.iterrows():
    pos = value.from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11[1][1]
    print (index, value)
```

But i haven't gone very far with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like your data:

```
df_match = pd.DataFrame( { "match_id" : [243221, 234251], 'league_id' : [26, 11], 
                          'from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11' : [ [(79066, 'GKP'), (82634, 'MID'), (79578, 'FWD'), (34765, 'DEF'), (23476, 'WING'), 
                                                                      (32456, 'MID'), (55897, 'DEF'), (45675, 'MID'), (32345, 'FWD'), (45765,'FWD'),
                                                                      (12354, 'WING')],
                                                                    [(14825, 'GKP'), (82634, 'MID'), (79578, 'FWD'), (34765, 'DEF'), (23476, 'WING'), 
                                                                      (32456, 'MID'), (55897, 'MID'), (45675, 'MID'), (32345, 'DEF'), (45765,'FWD'),
                                                                      (12354, 'WING')],
                                                                   ] }, index=[167, 1999])
```

Build a position mapping, noting that all are lists:

```
pmap = {'GKP' : [1], 'DEF': [3,4], 'WING' : [2,5], 'MID' : [6,7,8], 'FWD' : [9,10,11] }
```

Apply a lookup from the dictionary, choosing a random option, and then blowing up into individual columns. Rename the columns:

```
import random

tmp = df_match['from_home_player_1_to_home_player_11'].apply(lambda x: [ random.choice(pmap.get(pos, -1)) for n, pos in x]).apply(pd.Series)
tmp.columns = [f"home_player_X{i}" for i in range(1,12)]
```

Note that it puts `-1` in the position if the key isn't found. Then `pd.concat()` them together:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df_match, tmp], axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer. what is `get_pos_num()`?

Comment: That was a cut and paste mistake, sorry about that. I fixed it.